# How to log into a different account at VisualStudio.com?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, msdn

At some point I must have logged in with my personal account using my outlook.com credentials. Now, I can sign out, but when I click 'sign in' it automatically logs me in with my personal account and I don't have an option of logging in with my work credentials.

I'd prefer not to delete all cookies/cache. I am using IE 11

I have gone to https://login.microsoftonline.com/ and went to my account and clicked 'forget', but it still auto logs me into my outlook.com account when signing in.

Comment: You probably will have to delete the cookie, but you can delete just that cookie. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Rickjames I use IE 11 at work

Comment: use Incognito browser's windows and use Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can open a page by **InPrivate Browsing** for IE.

[image]

And then input your another VSTS account **username.visualstudio.com**, it will hint you to input you email and password.
[image]